# Using Stripe with Devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments

On Lines 3 and 15 on the second code snippet my IDE, it says Stripe is not defined. When I run the website and fill out a paid subscription form it gives me an action controller error and points me to certain files which are included herein (line 12 on the first code snippet).

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         
  belongs_to :plan
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token
  
  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end
end
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  // Watch for a form submission:
  $("#form-submit-btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    var error = false;
    var ccNum = $('#card_number').val(),
        cvcNum = $('#card_code').val(),
        expMonth = $('#card_month').val(),
        expYear = $('#card_year').val();
    if (!error) {
      // Get the Stripe token:
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }
    return false;
  }); // form submission
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    // Get a reference to the form:
    var f = $("#new_user");
    // Get the token from the response:
    var token = response.id;
    // Add the token to the form:
    f.append('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]" value="' + token + '" />');
    // Submit the form:
    f.get(0).submit(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: can you give us the error log? You have said there is an error in your IDE. What about the browser?

Comment: Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Users::RegistrationsController#create @sureshprasanna70 is this what you mean. this is the error i get on my browser

Comment: How have you initialized Stripe?

Comment: No, thats the thing, in the course im doing i dont remember us initializing stripe. Can you please help me with that @sureshprasanna70?

Comment: Have you included `Stripe.js`?

Comment: No, I dont have a stripe.js file. @sureshprasanna70

Comment: Include it and your javascript error would be corrected

Comment: How do i do this @sureshprasanna70???

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails